# transform url in php

Tags: php, url, character-encoding, encode

i have  a url in the form below

```
http://www.site.com/index.php?q=foo boo
```

when i visit the url through chrome, chrome tranform it properly to

```
http://www.site.com/index.php?q=foo%20boo
```

Now when i use file_get_contents with the first url , it doesnt read the url properly
while when i use the following url its ok

```
http://www.site.com/index.php?q=foo&nbsp;boo
```

what php function/functions should i use in order to convert the first link to the last one in order for the all special characters like space on the first link to be properly converted to `&nbsp;` like the last one?

Comment: This transformation with `&nbsp;` is wrong. If you really want to replace that space with non-breakable space character, use `0xA0` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP's `rawurlencode()`:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Comment: Click the check box to the left if I best answered your question

Answer (score 0):

A safer choice than replacing the breakable space with `&nbsp;` HTML entity is to replace it with the `\xA0` ASCII character. They are practically [equal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). The `&` character in an `URL` is considered as parameter separator and so the `&nbsp;` can cause only problems. The following algorythm can do what you are probably looking for:

```php
$url = 'http://www.site.com/index.php?q=foo boo&r=fii bii';
echo str_replace("\x20", "\xA0", $url);
// result: http://www.site.com/index.php?q=foo boo&r=fii bii (spaces are non-breakable)
echo str_replace("\x20", "&nbsp;", $url);
// result: http://www.site.com/index.php?q=foo&nbsp;boo&r=fii&nbsp;bii
```

More complicated algorythm:

```php
echo preg_replace_callback('/[\?&]\w+=([^&]+)/', create_function(
    '$matches',
    'return str_replace("\x20", "\xA0", $matches[0]);'
  ), $url);
// result: http://www.site.com/index.php?q=foo boo&r=fii bii (spaces are non-breakable)
```

And when these parameters are extracted:

```php
$arr = parse_url($url);
parse_str($arr['query'], $arr);
var_export($arr);
// result for \xA0  : array ( 'q' => 'foo boo', 'r' => 'fii bii', )
// result for &nbsp;: array ( 'q' => 'foo', 'nbsp;boo' => '', 'r' => 'fii', 'nbsp;bii' => '', ) // triple `&` in conflict
```